# How is the covalency of terminal carbons of a diamond satisfied?

Tags: covalent-compounds, carbon-allotropes, lattices

Are the terminal carbons of the diamond lattice remain bonded to some element like hydrogen?

Or, is it that they don't achieve octate in their outer shell?

Comment: They bond to whatever they can grab.

Comment: Probably just hydrogen atoms.